# Tell ESLint not to validate package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

ESLint is complaining that it can't download a package.json schema and I know it's because of our proxy and SSL issues which I'm just not gonna deal with now.

How can I tell the ESLint plugin in VSCode not to validate package.json?

I don't have an `.eslintignore` file but adding one with `package.json` doesn't help. If I run `npx eslint .` I get no lint errors but the VSCode ESLint plugin doesn't seem to care about `.eslintignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
   "./client", // Does not change the process's working directory
   { "directory": "./server", "changeProcessCWD": true }
 ]
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint

If this doesn't work I suggest you to research on open issues in the repo or open a new issue there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, package.json is parsed even though a have a .eslintignore containing package.json.
This behavior is not documented in https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#the-eslintignore-file, it states:

If an .eslintignore file is not found and an alternate file is not specified, ESLint will look in package.json for an eslintIgnore key to check for files to ignore

Clearly this is not true, since I have a .eslintignore and it still trying to load the package.json. :-/